# Firebase Flutter does not work in emulator

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

**I configured my flutter project with the Firebase CLI**,
I did it by following the necessary steps in flutter fire docs. I also did the manual installation for the emulator but my problem was not solved 
  Flutterfire documents : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

```
 My problem is this: 

  (V) Firebase plugins work when I compile it into Flutter WEB 

  (X) But it does not work in the emulator. 
 
   * I've done the SHA-KEY additions to the console firebase 

   * I've updated the google-services.json file.

   * I also updated two build gradle files
```

**I get the following errors when starting the application** 
   >> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   >> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  i also run the following console codes for this error
   `flutter pub upgrade`
   `flutter clean`
   `flutter run`

---

> **Video Link**

sorry for the watermark in the video :)
   if you see my problem as a video I hope i can be fully understood

[**issues screen record**](https://video.hizliresim.com/watch/XEMKPZHDRt)

---

> **main.dart file**

```dart
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

/*
...
*/

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, //Set status bar color
  ));
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  bool isIntroPass = await HelperFunctions.getAppIntroduction();
  runApp(KampApp(isPassIntro: isIntroPass));
}

class KampApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isPassIntro;
  const KampApp({super.key, this.isPassIntro = true});

  @override
  State<KampApp> createState() => _KampAppState();
}

class _KampAppState extends State<KampApp> {
  bool isLogged = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserLoggedStatus();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: Constants.appTitle,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: MyThemes.lightTheme(context),
      darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme(context),
      home: widget.isPassIntro
          ? isLogged
              ? const HomePage()
              : const LoginPage()
          : const IntroPage(),
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenarator.routeGenarator,
    );
  }
}
```

---

> **android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'//google services
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

> **android/app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'//google services
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mypackagename"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')//firebase bom
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'//mulitdex
}
```

Comment: Can you show a few of your codes?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply I've updated the question. what exactly are the codes you want, let me update the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

these are the warning messages you can ignore them, have you addded the firebase initializer in the main.dart file?

> > Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> > Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Need to add this line in main.dart

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(   options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform, );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i updated the question so you can look at the codes in detail